# Draw texture on touch in openGL iphone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es-2.0

Recently started with OpenGL, I have managed to draw a background image on screen and frame buffer. All works fine. Problem comes when I create new texture and add it to frame buffer.

> {
>
> ```
> [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
>
> glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
> glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);
>   // Clear screen
>  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
>
> //  Render player ship
>
>    [playerShip drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(160, 240)];
> // glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
> // [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
> }
> ```

If I uncomment the above two lines

> // glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
>
> // [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];

I dont get new texture which I am drawing through below code:

> NSInteger myDataLength = 20 * 20 * 4;
>       GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
>       glReadPixels(location.x-10, location.y-10, 20, 20, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

```
// gl renders "upside down" so swap top to bottom into new array.
// there's gotta be a better way, but this works.
GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
for(int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 20 * 4; x++)
    {
        buffer2[(19 - y) * 20 * 4 + x] = buffer[y * 4 * 20 + x];
    }
}

// make data provider with data.
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2, myDataLength, NULL);

// prep the ingredients
int bitsPerComponent = 8;
int bitsPerPixel = 32;
int bytesPerRow = 4 * 20;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

// make the cgimage
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(20, 20, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

// then make the uiimage from that
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
Texture2D *texture = [[Texture2D alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, self, nil, nil);

  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glLoadIdentity();
[texture drawAtPoint:location];
glPopMatrix();

glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glPushMatrix();
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
```

I dont know where I am doing mistake. I am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still rendering the background texture in your code and then render the space ship on top of it, the space ship might fail the depth buffer test.

Have you tried out:

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

to clear the z-buffer and then rendering the spaceship?

Comment: Since I am new to openGL please elaborate what you are talking about. How shall I proceed? What I have done is that correct way to proceed??? I am trying for image warp just like photobooth

Comment: @Dimple OpenGL comes with an optional depth buffer that's being used to detect visibility when drawing 3D scenes (foreground objects have a smaller z value than background objects so the app knows which pixels to draw). When just rendering 2D Textures like photos, the Z buffer can be counter productive and eventually prevent new textures from being rendered (depth buffer fight). Disabling the z buffer might help here. But i am not sure if that's your problem. Maybe posting a more complete example can help.